# Prove $\lim _{x\to +\infty }f\left(x\right)=L \iff \forall ε>0\exists M\forall x>M\forall y>M\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|<ε$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Prove $\lim _{x\to +\infty }f\left(x\right)=L \iff \forall ε>0\exists M\forall x>M\forall y>M\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|<ε$
>
> for every $ε>0$ exists  $M$ so that for every $x,y>M$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<ε$   $\iff$  $\lim _{x\to +\infty }f\left(x\right)=L $

to prove one direction I used :

the definition of the limit : $\forall ε>0\exists M\forall x>M\left|f\left(x\right)-L\right|<ε$

so we have : $|f(x)-L|<\frac{ε}{2}$ for every $x>M$

and for $y,x>M$

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|(f(x)-L)+(L-f(y))|\le|(f(x)-L)|+|(L-f(y))|\le \frac{ε}{2}+\frac{ε}{2}=ε$

so Is my prove correct and how to prove the other direction?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The `theorem-provers` tag is innapropriate.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  okey i removed it ,thanks

Comment: The proof in this direction is correct. For the proof in the other direction, are you allowed to use the theorem that every Cauchy sequence converges (which is a "discrete" version of what you want to prove)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you did is correct.

In order to prove it in the other sense, for each $n\in\mathbb N$ take $M_n\in\mathbb R$ such that$$x,y>M_n\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(y)\bigr|<\frac1n.$$We can (and will) assume that the sequence $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let$$a_n=\inf\bigl\{f(x)\,|\,x>M_n\bigr\}\text{ and }b_n=\sup\bigl\{f(x)\,|\,x>M_n\bigr\}.$$Then $b_n-a_n\leqslant\frac1n$ and, since the sequence $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing, $[a_n,b_n]\supset[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$. Take $L\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}[a_n,b_n]$; such a number exists by [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem#Statement_for_Real_Numbers). Now, prove that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=L$.

Comment: Of course you did't actually prove $\lim f(x)=L$ here; if you're proving _that_ you're not allowed to choose $L$. What you actually proved is $\exists L\lim f(x)=L$. (Yes, of course that's what you meant. Perhaps I'm being pedantic again. Or perhaps not: Given the way we see people mangle quanitifiers, simply omitting one in the statement of the theorem seems like a bad idea...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, you were not being pedantic *at all*. I should have noticed that and I didn't. I'm glad you did.

Answer (score 2):

The result you state is false (or at least very badly stated). It *must* be false! Suppose it's true that $\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)=L \iff \forall ε>0\exists M\forall x>M\forall y>M\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|<ε$ Since there is no $L$ in the second condition, it holds for $L=1$ if and only if it holds for $L=2$, so it follows that

> > $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=2$,

which is nonsense.

The correct version is this:

> > $\exists L\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)=L \iff \forall ε>0\exists M\forall x>M\forall y>M\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|<ε$ .

Which of course is what whoever stated the problem actually meant.

Comment: (+1) For noticing the obvious (not as easy as it seems).

Comment: I would never have caught this error. For me the problem reads like this: $f(x) $ tends to a limit as $x\to\infty$ if and only if some continuous version of Cauchy condition is met. This is a true and famous result and I would not have looked beyond. +1

Comment: Just to confirm : the original version of problem is like : $f(x) $ tends to a specific limit if and only if... I hope I am correct in this interpretation and then it is obviously false because Cauchy condition can only guarantee convergence, not convergence to a pre-specified number.

Comment: my question was that if $\lim _{x\to \infty }f\left(x\right)$ is exists and its finite if and only if ... , so i guess the statement is false

Comment: @J.Doe The statement $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ exists if and only if... is true. Otherwise, I wouldn't have proved it. What is wrong is to replace the first condition with $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=L$.

Comment: @J.Doe Already been said, but just for emphasis: "The limit exists" is not the same as "the limit equals $L$".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Right.